# In small claims court, can I sue for the time I spend putting together my case?

Tags: united-states, new-york-state, civil-law, small-claims-court

That is the time I spend gathering the necessary documentation and doing other things like filing at the court, going to court, collecting, etc., etc.

I would be representing myself obviously.

Comment: Which jurisdiction?

Comment: nyc - manhattan

Answer (score 3):

In the small claims court cases I've been involved in the judge has dismissed all aspects of the claim related to time wasted, transportation costs, and attending court in the judgement amount itself.

However the court costs one incurs should be a part of the amount that is judged in one's favour. Also the costs of enforcing any judgement (court bailiff fees) are usually considered recoverable.

My thoughts are that if one is keen to ensure that the other party pays the full costs of time, collation of evidence, photocopying, phone calls, and anything else one believes they are responsible for, one will have much more luck if one is not self-representing.

The predominant reason for self-representing is to keep costs, and thus one's financial risk from pursuing the case, minimal.

*disclaimer: this is only opinion, and not legal advice*

Comment: +1, ...similar experience